# Can't find polygons in database where point is within

Tags: c#, sql-server, spatial, point-in-polygon

I am trying to use a method to determine if a Lat,Long coordinate is within any of the stored polygons in the database and return a list of the ones it falls in (if any).

I have a lat/long of:

```
50.120578, -103.535156
```

I created a geofence and stored it in the database,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GeoFences] (
    [Id]           INT               IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [GeoPoints]    [sys].[geography] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.GeoFences] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

These are the values for the GeoPoints.

```
POLYGON ((-129.63729858398437 57.279042764977774, -92.899017333984375 56.8970039212726, -93.865814208984375 48.922499263758255, -122.86972045898437 48.806863461085172, -129.37362670898437 57.088515327886505, -129.63729858398437 57.279042764977774))
```

Using this method, I expect it to return that row as the polygon surrounds the point.

```
public IEnumerable<GeoFence> SearchGeoPoint(DbGeography geoPoint)
        {
            try
            {
                return _geoLocationRepository.Get.Where(obj => obj.GeoPoints.Intersects(geoPoint));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

However I keep getting no rows returned. I don't get any exceptions or errors, simply 0 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this was actually a few issues here and hopefully someone who experiences this issue will find this helpful.

First issue was that I was using a .Get.Where together in my LINQ query. When I removed the .Get and used the database context directly (I was using a generic repository) it returned the row(s) I expected.

I replaced

```
return _geoLocationRepository.Get.Where(obj => obj.GeoPoints.Intersects(geoPoint));
```

With

```
using(var context as DatabaseContext())
{
  var results = new List<GeoFence>();
  var query = context.GeoFences.Where(obj => obj.GeoPoints.Intersects(geoPoint));

  //Have to iterate through the results (Only way I've found to access the data)
  foreach(var fence in query)
{
   results.Add(fence);
}

return results;
}
```

The other thing to note is that you need to use Long/Lat to create your POINT not Lat/Long (You will get an exception if you do Lat/Long).

Comment: I had completely missed the .Get()!! I do however still question your polygon order, was it supposed to be the earth with a hole?  Additionally, if you want all results, you might consider the following, rather than iterating one by one: `var query = context.GeoFences.Where(obj => obj.GeoPoints.Intersects(geoPoint)).ToList(); return query;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your coordinates are defined in the wrong order and therefore your polygon actually represents the earth with "small" hole.

SqlGeography should "walk" the coordinates keeping the internal area on the left at all times.  This means that any holes defined in your polygon should however be walked the "opposite" way (which is still actually keeping the internal area of the polygon to your left).  In essence, you are defining that hole within the Earth.

In short, you need to reverse the coordinate order to get the correct result (and the one you are looking for).  If you're using SQL Server 2012, try the `ReorientObject()` method:

```
DECLARE @geog GEOGRAPHY = (SELECT [GeoPoints].ReorientObject() FROM [dbo].[GeoFences] WHERE [Id] = <an id>);
SELECT @geog;
```

I will advise however that `ReorientObject()` really is only a temporary fix in this scenario.  You need to permanently 'Reorient' all stored Polygons - if they are defined using the correct order.